# Passing UIGestureRecognizer events to child TableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I currently have a setup of:

A RootVC, with a UIPanGestureRecognizer on self.view. Then the RootVC has a child UITableViewController and hence UITableViewController.view is a subview of self.view.

The cells on the UITableViewController also have gesture recognizers enabling them to be swiped sideways. This works perfectly when the UITableViewController is itself the root view controller.

My issue is that im trying to pass a specific gesture from the self.view gesture recognizer down to the table cells. I've tried delegates:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

and

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

I can correctly identify the gestures i want to be sent below and return NO in that instance but that seems to cancel the gesture instead of passing it to subviews.

I know i could just call

```
[self.view.subviews[0] gestureShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer];
```

But because its the table view cells i cannot determine which cell the gesture should be sent too.

I have been thinking something like

```
[[self.childViewControllers[0] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] gestureShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer];
```

Would work but i dont know how to determine the correct indexPath..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point

You'll need to translate the point of the gesture to the coordinates for the tableView first.